# Type From right to left html / php

Tags: php, html, right-to-left

I want to make input from with right to left template. I want the first word I type to be placed in the right-most side of the text.

Here's an example:

```
WORD ; 12345
```

So I have to type `5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1`.
i'm trying to use `direction: rtl`, but it just changes the template text from left to right.

```html
<input type="number" style="direction: rtl; background-color: #424242; color: #FFFFFF;border: 0px; width: 350px; font-size: 100px" id="hasil" autofocus="true" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==16){check(); return false;}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this JSFiddle I just made, this should work for you.

```
.right {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/db5dvvut/1/